# highcharts - Series Data X and Y value?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, highcharts, linechart

I have a line chart that displays the time frame of:

4th August - 5th August,  using the datetime type on the X axis. I've been attempting to enter series data of Y-values such as:

```
[355, 345, 340, 340, 330, 330, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 
300, 300, 300, 400, 580, 585, 585, 585, 645, 645, 495, 495, 545, 545, 545, 645, 
645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645,
 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645, 645]
```

And I want these Y-values to mach up with the following:

```
[00:00, 00:01, 00:02, 00:30, 00:31, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00, 02:30, 03:00, 
03:30, 04:00, 04:30, 05:00, 05:30, 06:00, 06:30, 06:50, 07:00, 07:18, 07:19, 
07:30, 07:54, 08:00, 08:30, 08:45, 08:54, 08:59, 09:00, 09:20, 09:30, 10:00, 
10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30,
16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 
21:30, 22:00, 22:30, 23:00, 23:30, 00:00]
```

I know I could create the X-values as categories, but the data is being retrieved from a database, so the number of points can change and the specific values can change.

Basically, my issue is that I want my X-axis range to always stay the same, wich is easy enough. However as I'm drawing 3 lines on the same pair of axis, I require the points to be in different places on the X-axis due to the times being different.

Comment: What is the issue? What you have tried so far?

Comment: @LoganathanMohanraj I want to know how to plot the line with the specific values. I have a set X-axis scale. But I want to draw 3 lines on the graph with different x and y values each. How do I approach this?

Comment: You can define [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) or dynamically by [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner). What is important, time require to be timestamp (time in milisecods). Date.UTC() function should be useful when you convert your dates from database to correct format, during preprocessing.